# How to show changes to textarea live on website

Tags: html, web

I've a website with several `textareas` I want all people accessing the website at the time to be able to write text in a 'textarea` so it is visible for everyone looking at the page at the time.

No security is needed, it's for a family game.

Is this something that is even possible?

Comment: I think socket.io can help you

Answer (score 1):

I work a lot with real-time, here are a few alternatives and some demos I have created about the subject:

- Use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to build a small two-way message relay system. You can see a sample of this in less than 100 lines to create a text area that works like a Google Docs document here: http://adelriosantiago.com/gitblog/eng/litepad. A demo and repository are included inside the article.
- Use [shareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) if you want more flexibility. There is a sample of a textarea [here](https://github.com/share/sharedb/tree/master/examples/textarea) which you can use as a starting point *or* you can use the [boy.dog](http://boy.dog/) framework *(disclaimer: I maintain boy.dog)* especially if you don't want to start from scratch. With boy.dog you can make a real-time collaborative website in just 3 lines. It uses ShareDB internally and supports binding attributes like `class` and `id` to the real-time values.

[image]

- If you want a ready-made solution you can use [Etherpad Lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite). Etherpad is pretty much like a Google Docs document and there are many plugins to extend it.